# python dataframe datetime condition

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to create a new dataframe from an existing one by conditioning holiday datetime. train dataframe is existing and I want to create train_holiday from it by taking day and month values of holiday dataframe, my purpose is similar below:

```
    date    values
2015-02-01  10
2015-02-02  20
2015-02-03  30
2015-02-04  40
2015-02-05  50
2015-02-06  60

    date
2012-02-02
2012-02-05
```

now first one is existing, and second dataframe shows holidays. I want to create a new dataframe from first one that only contains 2015 holidays similar below:

```
 date      values
2015-02-02  20
2015-02-05  50
```

I tried

```
train_holiday = train.loc[train["date"].dt.day== holidays["date"].dt.day]
```

but it gives error. could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

In your problem you care only the month and the day components, and one way to extract that is by `dt.strftime()` ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)). Applying that extraction on both `date` columns and use `.isin()` to keep month-day in `df1` that matches that in `df2`.

```
df1[
    df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m%d').isin(
    df2['date'].dt.strftime('%m%d')
    )
   ]
```

Make sure both `date` columns are in date-time format so that `.dt` can work. For example,

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
```